# Adding unique index based on boolean value

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL table with the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scraped_movers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `is_headquarter` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `last_update` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`)
)
```

In this table, `is_headquarter` is a `BOOLEAN`. The combinaition of `[name, is_headquarter]` is UNIQUE when is_headquarter is true.
It means that for one name, there is only one headquarter, but it is possible to have multiple line with the same name and is_headquarter equals to `false`.

I would like to know if it is somehow possible to add a unique index on these columns or not ?

Comment: you could instead make a headquarters table, and enforce this with a unique foreign key constraint

Comment: can you have a headquarter (only one) with the same name as a non-headquarter at the same time?